# how can I have equal height children element in the different elements?

Tags: html, css

If I want to set the class=a div the same height and set the class=b div the same height ,the content is not the same ,the height need auto fit the content, li has the same height, too.
how can I write the css?

```
  <ul style="display:flex">
        <li>
          <div class="a">
            <h1>1</h1>
            <p>a...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="b">
            <h1>1</h1>
            <p>b...</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="a">
            <h1>1</h1>
            <p>c...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="b">
            <h1>1</h1>
            <p>d...</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="a">
            <h1>1</h1>
            <p>e...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="b">
            <h1>1</h1>
            <p>f...</p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

I have set class=a div the same height, but when the browser width gets smaller, the content  will overflow

[This is the effect I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHnw7.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks，I have add a pic and hope it can help

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<div class="a">` instead of `<div className="a">`.

ClassName is property of Element, you use it to access div attribute "class", but  from JavaScript. In HTML you just set "class" attribute instead. And your example is example of HTML.

You may find these links useful to understand difference between class and className:

1. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className

A small example:

```css
div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: yellow
}

.a {
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<div classname="a">First box</div>
<br>
<div class="a">Second box</div>
```

Comment: sorry,I am using react.I just wanna make an example